# Calculating $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{[0, \infty)} \frac{\sin(e^x) }{1+nx^2}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I want to calculate the limit of following Lebesgue-integral:

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{[0, \infty)} \frac{\sin(e^x) }{1+nx^2}\,\mathrm dx$$

Therefore I wanted to apply  Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.
$f_n(x)$ is measurable and $ f_n \rightarrow 0$ pointwise. Now it holds:

$$ \left|\frac{\sin(e^x) }{1+nx^2}\right| \leq \frac{1}{1+x^2} :=g(x)  $$

The improper integral over does  converge. That means f is  lebesgue integrable. 
Therefore 
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{[0, \infty)} \frac{\sin(e^x) }{1+nx^2}\,\mathrm dx =   \int_{[0, \infty)} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin(e^x) }{1+nx^2}\,\mathrm dx =0$$
Consider $ f_n(0) = sin 1$ does not converge to $ 0$. So I can't apply the theorem, can I ?

Comment: you can bound by $(1+x^2)^{-1}$ instead

Comment: That doesn't mean that $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable; it means that your $g$ is not chosen properly.

Comment: Ah ok. Then i can apply the theorem. So $  \int lim_n f_n = 0$

Comment: Is that right then?

Comment: $f_n(0) = sin(1) $ cannot converge to 0. Does this matter?

Comment: The convergence only needs to hold pointwise almost everywhere.

Comment: I see:) Then the integral is 0, isn't it?

Comment: @Leon1998 It means $f_n \to f$ where $f(x)=0$ for all $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=1$.  Is the Lebesgue integral of this function any different from $0$?

Comment: @ErickWong : I thougt it doesn't matter, wether there is one exception?

Comment: @Leon1998 I’m explaining to you *why* it doesn’t matter.  You don’t have to relax or alter the statement of dominated convergence in order to make this work.

Comment: The point $\{0\}$ at which point wise convergence fails os of Lebesgue measure 0, so do not worry about that. Dominated convergence is not concerned with what happens on sets of measure 0.

Comment: @OliverDiaz  Thank you:) I understand that now.

Comment: @ErickWong: Thank you:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are on the right track: apply Lebesgue's dominated convergence with $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ which is Lebesgue integrable in $[0,+\infty)$. Since $f_n(x)=\frac{\sin(e^x) }{1+nx^2}\to 0$ for all $x>0$  the sequence $(f_n)_n$ converges to zero *[almost everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere)* on $[0,+\infty)$, that's enough for dominated convergence, and we may conclude that the limit of $\int_0^{\infty} f_n(x)\,dx$ is zero.

Alternative way (without dominated convergence):
$$\begin{align}\left|\int_{[0, \infty)} \frac{\sin(e^x) }{1+nx^2}\, dx \right|&\leq \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{|\sin(e^x) |}{1+nx^2}\, dx\\
&\leq \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{1+nx^2}=\left[\frac{\arctan(\sqrt{n}x)}{\sqrt{n}}\right]_0^{+\infty}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{n}}.\end{align}$$
So, again, the limit as $n\to\infty$ is zero.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Good point! I revised my answer.